# How to find if defrag session is finished on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, command-line, defragment

I decided to defrag my C drive using the GUI and left overnight to run. Eventually though, I became unable to maximize the progress window and therefore, don't know if the process is complete or not.

I tried hotkey tricks, cascading windows etc. but can't maximise the window.

Subsequently, I tried using the Windows command line **defrag** function to see if I could determine if the defrag process was finished or not, but am unsure if it would take into account the GUI.

In normal circumstances I wouldn't mind force closing the GUI, but I am afraid that doing so during a defrag session will cause damage.

Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: Look in task manager under processes, see if defrag.exe is running.

Comment: @Moab I don't see defrag.exe but I do see Service Host: Disk Defragmenter in Processes and defragsvc in the Services tab.

Answer (score 2):

First, defrag ONLY applies to Hard Drives, not SSD drives.

If you have a HDD, and defragged it, it will finish and the dialogue likely then disappeared.  No issue with that.

If you wish to check, you will need to run it again, wait for it and see the end of it.

If you go to Admin Tools, Optimize and Defragment, then click on Analyse, it will analyse and tell you if the drive is OK 0% or if it needs to be defragged.

**Once Set UP:**  Let defrag run itself automatically. There is no need to run manually and certainly not frequently.

If you have SSD, do not even use it.

This should help you.

Comment: I made sure to only do it to a HDD but I appreciate the advice. To clarify, are you saying to try and run the GUI again and see what happens? Thanks.

Comment: Yes, just run the GUI again and watch it.

Comment: I clicked **Optimise** from the properties menu of my C drive but, apart from the minimised GUI icon flashing briefly, nothing happened sadly.

Comment: You said you have a HDD and Optimize is only for SSDs.  Use the Defrag option (not Optimize)

Comment: The button labelled **Optimise** is in a box labelled **Optimise and degragment drive**. Assuming we are talking about the same program, would fragment/optimise be used interchangeably?

Comment: The icon from Admin Tools IS labelled Optimize and Defragement. So you can use this. Then when you click on that, click on Analyse and that will analyse the HDD. It will tell you if you need to defragment. If it says OK 0% or some small percent, you are done and need do no more.  I clarified my answer

Comment: Thanks but the problem is that I can't maximise the GUI to see the progress/status of fragmentation, it is minimised to the taskbar if that makes sense.

Comment: Restart your computer, make sure everything is closed and then try opening Admin Tools, Optimize and Defragment again. I did it here to test to make sure it works.

Comment: The only issue with that is that I would have to force close the GUI and I heard that force closing during fragmentation isn't a good idea.

Comment: Let it wait for (say) an hour and then close it. That is your only option because you need to restart to get it working correctly.